# WP ACF Relationship Как отыскать все посты с одинаковыми связями?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

В плагине ACF используется произвольное поле типа - [Relationship](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) что бы связать post с кастомными постами . В моем случаи посты - это команды, а кастомные посты игроки. (football-players)

[image: команды]

Подскажите, пожалуйста как в переменную получить значение id кастомных постов которым была назначена одинаковая команда? Как получить массив id из игроков одной команды?

Comment: [Querying relationship fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/#single-location.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот правильный ответ. Может, ещё кому понадобится:

```html
<div class="players-slider players-slider-swiper swiper">
    <?php
    if( $posts ):
        foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT)
            setup_postdata($post);
            $seriesID = get_the_ID();
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly
    endif;
    $team = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'football-players',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'player_team',
                'value'   => '"' . $seriesID . '"',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ),

    ));
    ?>
    <ul class="players-slider__list swiper-wrapper">
    <?php
    if ($team->have_posts()) {
        while ($team->have_posts()) {
            $team->the_post();
            $post = get_post(get_the_ID());
            ?>
            <li class="players-slider__item swiper-slide">
                <img class="players-slider__img" src="images/_football-players/Andriy-Shevchenko.png" width="307" height="422" loading="lazy" alt="Andriy Shevchenko">
                <a class="players-slider__name" href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
                <span class="players-slider__number">7</span>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```